# How to JUnit test my cloning method?

Tags: java, junit, cloning

I have a clone method in my `Student` class and I'm trying to test if it is working as expected (dob and address and deep cloned and course is shallow cloned)

I need help with the second chunk of code, I'm not sure how to correctly test if address and dob are deep cloned and course is shallow cloned

...

```
public Student clone() {
    Student clone = new Student();
    clone.dob = (Date) this.dob.clone();
    clone.address = this.address.clone();
    clone.course = this.course;
    return clone;
}
```

...

```
public void testCloning() {
    Student test = clone?
    assertEquals(Student, Student.clone())
}
```

Comment: Please explain your question properly.

Comment: What about writing an equals() method (of course only if they also should be treated as equal)

Comment: Are address and dob arrays or other object? If not, I'm not sure  I understand why you think a deep copy applies to them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to test in this way, you should override `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods by specifying all fields you want to clone.

Now, is suitable and effective to override  `equals()` and `hashcode()` with all fields if a more elementary information can identify one `Student` instance ?

As alternative way would be to compare that values of the fields are the same with field accessors.
Besides, fields with deep cloning should also be asserted by checking that objects are not the same and fields with shallow cloning could be simply asserted by checking that objects are the same.

You could do it for example :

```
@Test
public void cloning() {
    Student original = new Student(....); // 
    ...
    Student cloned = original.clone();
    // deep check
    assertEquals(original.getDob(), cloned.getDob());
    assertEquals(original.getAddress(), cloned.getAddress());
    assertNotSame(original.getDob(), cloned.getDob());
    assertNotSame(original.getAddress(), cloned.getAddress());

   // shallow check    
   assertSame(original.getCourse(), cloned.getCourse());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check with a combination of `equals` and `==`.

When you do a deep clone, you want to have a new object, which equals the old one. With a shallow copy, the object should be the same. So, you could check as follows:

```
public void testCloning() {
    Student original = new Student(); 
    //Fill in values for original
    Student clone = original.clone();
    assertEquals(Student, Student.clone());

    //Check like this for all deep cloned values
    assertTrue(student.getAddress().equals(clone.getAddress()));
    assertFalse(student.getAddress() == clone.getAddress());

    //Check like this for all shallow cloned values
    assertTrue(student.getCourse() == clone.getCourse());
}
```

Since `equals` has to return true (if it is implemented correctly), you don't have to check for `equals` with shallow clones.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to test if it is working as expected (dob and address and deep cloned and course is shallow cloned)
>
> ```
>   public void testCloning() {
>     Student test = clone?
>     assertEquals(Student, Student.clone())
> }
> ```

`assertEquals()` depends on the implementation of `equals()` in the `Student` class. If you did not implement it any two objects of class `Student` will return `false`.

A meaningful implementation will return `true`  if both compared `Student` objects have equal content in their member variables regardless of if they share the *same* objects in them or clones. Therefor you have to check your requirement (also clone member variable content) by explicitly checking that the members of the cloned `Student` are different objects:

```
@Test
public void cloneCreatesDeepCopy() {
    // arrange
    Student original = new Student(/*any properties*/);

    // act
    Student cloned = original.clone();

    // assert
    assertEquals("a clone should be equal to its original" ,original , cloned );

    assertEquals("name is equal" ,original.getName() , cloned.getName() );
    assertFalse("Name is a different string object", original.getName() == cloned.getName());

    assertEquals("last name is equal" ,original.getLastName() , cloned.getLastName() );
    assertFalse("last Name is a different string object", original.getLastName() == cloned.getLastName());
  // and so on...
}
```